# Is Gimpshop equally good as Gimp?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I am a photoshop user who is looking for a free alternative.
Gimp is usually the answer.  When looking for downloads I stumbled upon 'gimpshop', a gimp distro that is layout for the convenience of photoshoppers.

But is it equally good as Gimp?

Comment: Peter, welcome to GD.  Can you provide more detail about what "good as Gimp" means?  Otherwise this question seems unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks.  With "As good as" I mean essentially the same,since it is supposedly the same engine.  I didn't know if all feautures are kept and if the release is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most branches of the GIMP are typically several versions behind the main release. But, yes, it's the same 'core' application under the hood.

Comment: And my never asked side-wondering, 'are they up to date' is answered too.

Answer (score 1):

GIMPshop is based on GIMP 2.2. GIMP is currently at 2.7.x. It's over than 5 years behind.